# Physics.CheckSphere (and similar) don't always work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am spawning spheres and want them to not intersect. The script mostly works, but I always get a few spheres intersecting - in couples or threes close to each other.

I've tried all the methods - `CheckSphere`, `OverlapSphere`, also the same methods for `box` and `mesh`, tried randomizing the position ontriggerenter with another sphere - nothing's helping.

```
void CreateObject(Vector3 v)
{
    _myObj = Instantiate(ballPrefab, _cloneParent);
    _myObj.transform.localPosition = v;
    _myObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    SpawnedObjects.Append(_myObj);
}

SpawnedObjects = new GameObject[_amountRandomized];

_cloneParent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SurfaceFlag").transform;
const float objectSize = 105f;
for (var i = 0; i < _amountRandomized; i++)
{
    var randomizedPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-DistanceFromCenter, DistanceFromCenter), SpawnDepth, Random.Range(-DistanceFromCenter, DistanceFromCenter));
    while (Physics.CheckSphere(_cloneParent.transform.TransformPoint(randomizedPos), objectSize, 10))
    {
        Debug.Log(Physics.CheckSphere(_cloneParent.transform.TransformPoint(randomizedPos), objectSize, 10));
        randomizedPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-DistanceFromCenter, DistanceFromCenter), SpawnDepth, Random.Range(-DistanceFromCenter, DistanceFromCenter));
    }

    CreateObject(randomizedPos);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Collectible"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Moving sphere");
        _transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-_distanceFromCenter, _distanceFromCenter), Gameplay.SpawnDepth, Random.Range(-_distanceFromCenter, _distanceFromCenter));
    }
    _goDown = false; //trigger to move 6f downwards with Lerp
    _goUp = true; //same but upwards
    _startTime = Time.time;
}
```

Not getting any error messages.

Comment: Where/in which method is the codeblock starting with `_cloneParent = ...` called?

Comment: *`nothing's helping. Not getting any error messages.`* Define "not working." Just because there aren't error messages doesn't mean your code is right. But that said, the code you have shared won't compile.

Comment: It does compile) Not working - I get spawned objects intersecting.